# isNan function makes the next line of code not work

Tags: javascript, html

So, this is my jsfiddle right here:

https://jsfiddle.net/therealnemis/dxrdo9km/87/

As you can see in heron(), I have three lines of code, the third one is to change the tag with "answer" in it, a h3 tag in my HTML. If I put the tag in the second line, then the code will execute when I press the button labeled "Something":

```
    var answer = squareRoot(15);

  //If the answer is NaN, this is due to the fact that the triangle is not possible.
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = squareRoot(15);
 result = checkIfRealTriangle(answer);
```

This works when I press the button labeled Something, because the document.GetElementById is before the checkIfRealTriangle, which incorporates the isNaN function. If I move the getelementbyID to below the isNaN function, then nothing will happen when I press the button labeled Something. If I get rid of isNaN, everything works.

Comment: @gforce301 or you could just, you know, help the guy out.

Comment: oh sorry man, since I'm using JSfiddle I didn't think to use console. Thanks

Comment: @TrevorYokum I did. I pointed out the errors in the console.

Comment: @gforce301 wow. Just wow.

Comment: fixed it, forgot to define a variable in the function. Thanks

Comment: @TrevorYokum Look man I didn't make the rules here but I know how to read them. Per this: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Specifically: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." This post is considered off topic. I didn't flag it to be closed now did I?

Comment: @gforce301 First off, I thought I made it clear what I wanted my code to do in the OP. I wrote the instances of what worked, and what I  thought that was my problem. I don't normally code, and when I do, it's usually Java where the program won't run if something's wrong anyways. I forgot to use the console, forgive me for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem function:

```
function checkIfRealTriangle(answer) {
  var output;
  if (isNaN(answer)) {
    output = "Your sides do not make a real triangle. Check your numbers and try again";
  } else {
    output = "The Area of your triangle is " + area;
  }
  return output;
}
```

This function is returning the following error when passing a number that returns false for isNaN (i.e. 15):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: area is not defined
>       at checkIfRealTriangle (:8:48)
>       at :1:1

You need to replace "area" with "answer" like so:

```
function checkIfRealTriangle(answer) {
  var output;
  if (isNaN(answer)) {
    output = "Your sides do not make a real triangle. Check your numbers and try again";
  } else {
    output = "The Area of your triangle is " + answer;
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: got it, how do I select answer as a question?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the "area" variable that you have in your `checkIfRealTriangle(answer)` function. If you look in the console, you'll see the error.